# addClass and removeCLass in JS with loading content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass, removeclass

I have problem with addClass and removeCLass in JS. I would like to do sth like that:

But I have a content div where I load files in PHP. But when I load sth the script resets and first li is selected. Scheme: 
I click on Events, it gets new class and the content is load. Now when I click events, page loads and I see the content but class in first li. 
How to change it?

EDIT: 
OK guys I change code but it still doesn't work as I want. **When I chenge "#" in links to url, the page loads as new and I lost this JS**. (It starts again).

CODE:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MB1").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
  $("#MB2").removeClass("active");
  $("#MB3").removeClass("active");
  $("#MB4").removeClass("active");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MB2").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
  $("#MB1").removeClass("active");
  $("#MB3").removeClass("active");
  $("#MB4").removeClass("active");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MB3").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
  $("#MB1").removeClass("active");
  $("#MB2").removeClass("active");
  $("#MB4").removeClass("active");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MB4").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
  $("#MB1").removeClass("active");
  $("#MB2").removeClass("active");
  $("#MB3").removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
#menu-div ul{
list-style-type:none;
}

.button a{
text-decoration: none;
color:green;
}

.button  a:hover{
color: red;
}

.button.active a{
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-div"> 
<ul>
<li id="MB1" class="button active"><a href="?id=start">Home</a></li>
<li id="MB2" class="button"><a href="?id=pro">Projects</a></li>
<li id="MB3" class="button"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li id="MB4" class="button"><a href="?id=con">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you assign the click action using

```
$('#menu li a').on('click', function(){
    $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

is that only the existing objects receive the event-handler.

You want to use something like this instead:

```
$("body").on('click', '#menu li a', function(){
    $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

By making `body` the target, even if the data loads after the script, the event-handler will be set.
In addition, any subsequent changes to the menu won't require you to reset the event handler.

---

**EDIT**

Per the changes to your example code:

1. When you have `<a href="#"` and so on, pressing the link does not make you leave the page.
2. You changed some of the links to `<a href="?something"` and so on. Clicking this link, the whole page is reloaded with the new querystring.

Are the links supposed to get data asynchronously?
If **YES**, you should return the jquery to the way it was... and use my answer above instead of the one you used of `$(document).ready({[...]`.

If **NO**, I would suggest that you use PHP to make sure that the correct menu item is set to `active`.
Something along the lines of (**I don't actually know php... this code may be completely off**):

```
<a href="?whatever" class="button <?php if(request.querystring = "whatever") echo "active"; ?>
<a href="?something" class="button <?php if(request.querystring = "something") echo "active"; ?>
```